# How to substitute negative values with a calculated value in an entire dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a huge dataframe with many negative values in different columns that should be equal to their original value*0.5. 
I've tried to apply many R functions but it seems I can't find a single function to work for the entire dataframe.
I would like something like the following (not working) piece of code:

```
mydf[] <- replace(mydf[], mydf[] < 0, mydf[]*0.5)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do,

```
mydf[mydf<0] <- mydf[mydf<0] * 0.5
```

If you have values that are non-numeric, then you may want to apply this to only the numeric ones,

```
ind <- sapply(mydf, is.numeric)
mydf1 <- mydf[ind]
mydf1[mydf1<0] <- mydf1[mydf1<0] * 0.5
mydf[ind] <- mydf1
```

Comment: This solution fails saying something like:
'not numeric argument transformed to binary operator'

Comment: Do you have columns that are not numeric?

Comment: Yes, maybe some data is missing.

Comment: Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Comment: Ok. Can you please provide a reproducible sample of your data?

Comment: The solution by Tim works ok. I like it. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `lapply()` on the entire data frame, making the replacements on each column in succession.

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) {
    x <- ifelse(x < 0, x*0.5, x)
})
```

The `lapply()`, or list apply, function is intended to be used on lists, but data frames are a special type of list so this works here.

## Demo

Comment: Thanks, this work. I just added as.data.frame to convert the list back to a dataframe.
`df <-as.data.frame( lapply(df, function(x) {
    x <- ifelse(x < 0, x*0.5, x)
}))`

Answer (score 0):

In the `replace` the `values` argument should be of the same length as the number of TRUE values in the `list` ('index' `vector`)

```
replace(mydf, mydf <0, mydf[mydf <0]*0.5)
```

---

Or another option is `set` from `data.table`, which would be very efficient

```
library(data.table)
for(j in seq_along(mydf)){
  i1 <- mydf[[j]] < 0
  set(mydf, i = which(i1), j= j, value = mydf[[j]][i1]*0.5)
 }
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
```